# Transforming this JSON via underscore or a javascript utility library?

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I have some JSON that looks as so:

```
[{"target": "mydata.12.2", "datapoints": [[763.7, 1368821100], [762.1, 1368821160], [223.11, 1368821220], [886.54, 1368821280], [112.3, 1368821340]]}]
```

I'd like to remove the first key and surrounding array brackets so it reads:

```
{"datapoints": [[763.7, 1368821100], [762.1, 1368821160], [223.11, 1368821220], [886.54, 1368821280], [112.3, 1368821340]]}
```

My javascript parsing skills leave a bit to be desired and I was hoping someone could help.  Perhaps underscore.js has something that could assist here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for a library. Supposing your first array is called obj1, you just have to do

```
var obj2 = obj1[0];
delete obj2['target'];
```

Note that you seem to have no JSON here, just plain javascript objects.

Supposing you really want to start from JSON and get some JSON at end, parse then stringify :

```
var obj2 = JSON.parse(json1);
delete obj2['target'];
var json2 = JSON.stringify(obj2);
```

Comment: Thank you sir.  The json/javascript objects I posted came as output from the Graphite charting tool, which has a `&format=json` querystring flag you can use to deliver raw data instead of a chart.